# Problem with scrolling in HorizontalPager in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a code for horizontal pager:

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box {
            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                    start = if (pagerState.currentPage == 0) 16.dp else 32.dp,
                    end = if (pagerState.currentPage == list.size - 1) 16.dp else 32.dp,
                ),
                pageSpacing = 8.dp,
                pageCount = list.size
            ) { page: Int ->
                val item = list[page]
                item.let {
                    Card(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .clickable {
                                onItemClicked()
                            }
                            .carouselTransition(
                                page,
                                pagerState
                            ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                    ) {
                        CarouselBox(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

problem is when I want to move to second page, pager moves to third page, moving fast missing the second one. When I do it slowly everything is ok. It happen only for second item and only when I move from first to second. It is not happen when I am back from third to second. When I set padding only 32.dp everything is ok, but I want to move first page to left of screen and the last item to right part of screen.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to adjust the contentPadding based on the transition direction. You can use the pagerState.isScrollInProgress property to determine if the pager is currently scrolling, and adjust the padding accordingly.

Here's an example modification to your code:

```
HorizontalPager(
   state = pagerState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        start = if (pagerState.currentPage == 0) 16.dp else if (pagerState.isScrollInProgress && pagerState.currentPage == 1) 16.dp else 32.dp,
        end = if (pagerState.currentPage == list.size - 1) 16.dp else 32.dp,
    ),
    pageSpacing = 8.dp,
    pageCount = list.size
) { page: Int ->
    // Your existing code for creating each page
    val item = list[page]
    item.let {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onItemClicked()
                }
                .carouselTransition(
                    page,
                    pagerState
                ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        ) {
            CarouselBox(it)
        }
    }
}
```

This modification checks if the pager is currently in progress (pagerState.isScrollInProgress) and if the current page is the first one. If both conditions are met, it uses the smaller padding value (16.dp) to ensure a smooth transition from the first to the second page. Otherwise, it uses the larger padding value (32.dp).

Comment: in your solution first page works, but problem is between 2 and 3 page now :)